# Show the name of the containing folder in the Eclipse tab of a file

Tags: eclipse, tabs, editing

I have the same set of files in N folders, one of them, say, **blank.xhtml**. The files contain somewhat similar information and it is becoming overwhelming to figure out which file comes from which folder every time I switch between the tabs. When I open one of them to edit and happen to open a file with the same name from another folder I get confused and more often than not end up editing the wrong file: nullifying my hard work. So I am wondering if there is a way to show the name of a containing folder in the tab like this **G-06/blank.xhtml** or **G-07/blank.xhtml**. I will be very very thankful to anybody who has pointers to how I can make this happen.

Comment: You can put the mouse on the tab (without clicking) and the path will appear.

Comment: It is on top of main window.

Answer (score 6):

As an addition to the *Maroun's* answer there is an alternative solution.
**It's not exactly what you want** (full name in the tab's title), but may be useful sometimes.

In the "Project Explore" view (the same goes to "Navigator" view) click the "**Link with Editor**" button. That way, whenever you choose some file opened in the editor, it will be automatically selected/highlighted (see the picture) in the "Project Explorer" view.

Here is the picture:
[image]

Maybe this will be useful to you too.

Answer (score 1):

If you hover the mouse over the tab containing the file name then a popup appears showing the full path.  Not exactly what you wanted, but it should help.  (This with Eclipse Neon.3 Release 4.6.3 on a Mac).

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you're looking for, but ctrl+shft+e will open the switch editor window that shows all the open editors with their filepaths. I use this shortcut for the same reason. I'll have multiple build.gradle files open from multiple projects and this helps pick the correct one